# Cisco 4400 Series Initializing Hardware loop

Tags: cisco, hardware, boot

I am experiencing an issue with our Cisco 4400 router. Upon booting it gives a flashing STAT light along with a green PWR, TEMP, FAN, PSU0. It then restarts and the fan comes on briefly, and the router outputs "Initializing Hardware . . ." This process repeats over and over. No other errors are displayed. Any insight to this issue would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,
James

Comment: Had you recently performed an update? I'd [call TAC](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/web/tsd-cisco-worldwide-contacts.html).

Comment: Had you added or removed a card from your router ?

Comment: No updates have been performed. No cards have been tocuhed. This system was online roughly 2 months agoand worked fine, this is the first time it has come back online since.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a hardware problem.  If you have a maintenance contract with Cisco, you should give them a call.  If you don't, now would be the time to get one.

Comment: Note that if the router is still under warranty, you can also call them without having a support contract. (Warranty FAQ: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/warranty_qa_guest.html). Also, support contracts have a 1 month lead time, so if you buy one now you may have to wait to get a replacement unit (although if you are lucky you might get one sooner).